# How can I tell if MAGE algorithm will run on single core or will it use multiple cores?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm looking at the [MAGE Spellbook](https://memgraph.com/docs/mage/query-modules/available-queries) that lists available modules and graph algorithms. I want to use the best performant algorithms so I'm trying to chose the ones that have multicore capabilities. How can I tell if specific algorithm is implemented in such way that it can use single or more than one CPU core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the details for each algorithm in the Spellbok you will see among the characteristics note about **Parallelism**. If the value is `parallel` the algorithm has support for multicore, a and if the value is `sequential` then there is no support for multicore.